# How to reduce number picker dialog active size box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

[image: number picker]

how to reduce active number box border size in number picker

```
                <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: You can try adding `android:scaleY="0.8"` it will still have unnecessary padding

Comment: i used but top padding maintain like above image only reduce active box size

Comment: Ya the padding will be there , you can keep a hack like `android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"`  to hide extrapadding

Comment: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/23/35bc1ea6ec8f05f3e820764ad46487eb-full.jpg

not reduce this padding i used android:scaleY="0.8"

Comment: is `android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"` not working ?

Comment: this is working but looking text size small

Comment: You can increase or decrease `android:scaleY="0.8"`  as per your requirement